# Bypassing ptrace in gdb

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I found the following trick to use if a program uses `ptrace` to detect whether it is running in a debugger:

```
catch syscall ptrace
commands 1
set ($eax) = 0
continue
end
```

Can somebody explain me how is it working? I have tried to insert `i r eax` after `commands 1`, however I do not understand the negative values I have got:

```
Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall ptrace), 0x00007ffff778af1e in ptrace (request=PTRACE_TRACEME) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ptrace.c:45
45  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ptrace.c: No such file or directory.
eax            0xffffffda   -38

Catchpoint 1 (returned from syscall ptrace), 0x00007ffff778af1e in ptrace (request=PTRACE_TRACEME) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ptrace.c:45
45  in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ptrace.c
eax            0xffffffff   -1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ptrace` system call allows one process to trace another.  My guess is that your application (that is trying to detect the debugger) spawns a child process (or maybe thread) and then uses `ptrace` to attach to this child, just like a debugger would.

The catch is that only one process can trace another, if a second process tries to attach with `ptrace` then the second `ptrace` will fail, returning `-1` and setting `errno` to `EPERM`.  If you are running under a debugger then the debugger will have got in first and attached with `ptrace`, so when the application itself tries to attach with `ptrace` this call will fail.

So, in your example, when the catchpoint triggers on the *return* from syscall ptrace you can see that `eax` is set to -1, indicating that the syscall failed (register eax holds the return value on x86-64).

Now if the code in the application you are debugging is not very good, and it only checks to see if `ptrace` returns success or not, then forcing the value of `eax` to be 0 (where 0 indicates success for `ptrace`) *might* be enough to fool the application into thinking that it is not running under a debugger.

Obviously, it would be possible to write more complex code in the application that makes more extensive use of `ptrace` such that it would be *harder* (though not impossible) to work around this detection.